# Javascript: Form element values to a Collection

Tags: java, javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML page with dinamycally changing number of select elements.

```
    <script>
    function getValues() {
        var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select'),
        arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(selects),
        selectValues = arr.map(function (select) {
            return select.value;
    });
        return selectValues;
    }
    </script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function moreSelect() {
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        // Append a node with a random text
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name " + (i+1) + ": "));
        // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
        var input = document.createElement("select");
        input.name = "name" + (i+1);
        container.appendChild(input);
        // Append a line break 
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
</script>

<form action="action"method="POST" onsubmit="return getValues;">

                    More selects (max. 9):<br>
                <p>
                    <input type="number" id="name" name="name" value="0"
                        min="0" max="9"><br />
                    <button type="button" onclick="moreSelect()">Add</button>
                    <br>
                <p>
                    <br>
                <div id="container" /></div>

                <p>
                    <br> <br> <input type="submit" value="Go">
            </form>
```

I want to collect this values to a List or an Array before the POST method and give this parameter list to my Java controller like this:

```
@RequestParam("allValues") List<String> allValues
```

Edit: I edited it, but doesn't works.

Comment: Do you just want the values of each select or the names of them too? BTW: you don't have options in your selects?

Comment: Just the values. Yes I know it, I skip this part. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all selects, transform them to a real Array by `Array.prototype.slice`. Now you can use `map` to get all values. `getElementsByTagName` returns a `HTMLCollection`, that does not support `map()`, etc.

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select'),
    arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(selects),
    selectValues = arr.map(function (select) {
        return select.value;
    });
```

Now `selectValues` is an Array of the select values.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one hidden form parameter say with name "allValues" and using javascript before posting Form, you can add all select values in that parameter.

Comment: Okay, but how can I do this?

Comment: You can call function before submitting form like, <form onsubmit="return consolidateValues(this);"> and in this function you can actually getEelementById and iterate through values